# Using oc command inside fabric8

Tags: openshift, fabric8

What is the standard way of using "oc apply" command inside the java code using "Fabric8" library ?

We have been using client.buildConfigs().inNamespace ..... etc so far. However, felt using "oc apply" command can simplify code

Thanks
San

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean inside a Jenkins Pipeline or just in general purpose Java code?

We have the equivalent of kubernetes apply with:

```
new Controller().apply(entity);
```

in the kubernetes-api module in the fabric8io/fabric8 git repo.

There's a [similar API in kuberetes-client too](https://github.com/fabric8io/kubernetes-client#loading-resources-from-external-sources) which lets you apply a file or URI directly.

In pipelines we tend to use the `kubernetesApply(file)` function to do a similar thing.

But inside Jenkins Pipelines you can also just use `oc` or `kubectl` directly in pipelines using the `clients` docker image via the `clientsNode()` function in the fabric8-pipeline-library like [these examples](https://github.com/fabric8io/fabric8-pipeline-library#understanding-how-it-works) then you can run `oc` commands directly via [this code in a Jenkinsfile](https://github.com/fabric8io/fabric8-pipeline-library/blob/f2fd6429182d3cc03205eb7420798261455262f2/vars/deployRemoteOpenShift.groovy#L11-L12).